# Nested perfect-scrollbar scrolling both the div child as well as parent

Tags: angular, perfect-scrollbar

I am using [ngx-perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-perfect-scrollbar)

I have section with fixed height on the page. So, 2 perfect scrollbar one for page and other for section in the page.

But when scrolling inside section of the page (with the mouse click to test scroll on touch screen) and reaching the bottom OR top, the page scroll is also scrolling with the section scroll. And this is the problem.

Below is the sample of html code :

```
<perfect-scrollbar>
    <mat-card>
        some contents...
    </mat-card>

    <mat-card>
        <perfect-scrollbar> // when scrolling this, parent scrollbar also scrolling
           list of information....
        </perfect-scrollbar>
    </mat-card>

    <mat-card>
        some contents...
    </mat-card>
</perfect-scrollbar>
```

Let me know, How I can stop this behaviour ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey! I'm facing the same issue, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @barney.balazs Check on [github](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-perfect-scrollbar/issues/176)